# log4j problem in java enterprise application

Tags: java, log4j, ejb

I created a java enterprise application in Netbeans 6.8. It has ejb module and web application. I want to log all errors in catch block in my file. In web application, we would create log4.properties in /WEB-INF/classes. But, in ejb module, we don't have anything like /WEB-INF folder. So where should i paste this file? so that i don't get error as "appender cannot be found". This should be very easy for java experts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be pasted under the indivual module folder, please try once there

Comment: Cool! Thanks! i directly pasted in source packages folder and it worked like a charm :)